# Two line text background with shadow

Tags: html, css

This is what i´m trying to achieve:

[image]

But I can´t make the background be as long as the text while keeping the shadow with the whole content... I just get this:

[image]

As you can see it makes two shadows... this is my markup and css:

```
<span class="interior_title">Samsung, HP Pop-Tops Do Double Duty <br>Rich Jaroslovsky</span>

span.interior_title{
    background: #c7c7c9;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #2f2f31;
    width: 550px;
    font-family: 'chaletcomprime';
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 47px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px #000;
}
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: i think you might need to separate the two lines into two spans

Comment: it will happen the same, two spans = two shadows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Ttm/16/)

It's close to what you want.
I made it like this. Two elements floated left one under the other one. Same style only the width is different.

```
<span class="one">Extra line here bal bal bal </span>
<span class="two">Line TwoM<span>
```

Now the problem here was the extra shadow that was casting on `.two`, I fixed that by using

```
.two:before{
    background: tan;
    content: "";
    height: 10px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%; }
```

Don't worry about IE, because `:before` work on IE8 as for the `box-shadow` it stops at IE9.